# how to get audio file from an QByteArray

Tags: qt, audio, qfile, qbytearray

I capture sound   form microphone  with QAudioInput,and save it  in Buffer  now I want to save  this sound in  Qfile for example audio.wav. I try this  code.

```
QByteArray data;
QFile file("C:/asus/audio.wav");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write(data);
file.close();
```

this code doesn't work , when I play Audio.wav , its not the sound that I've captured

thank yo for help

Comment: If the `data` array just contains the PCM data you'll have to add [a WAV header to it](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).

Comment: Check the return values of open() and write()